# Создание правильного запроса

Tags: sql, mysql

Как правильно сделать вот этот запрос:

```
SELECT ID,post_title,(
  SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = (
    SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "%д.%" AND post_type = "post";
  )
) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "%д.%" AND post_type = "post";
```

По сути это два запроса:

```
SELECT id,post_title FROM wp_posts
   WHERE post_title LIKE "%д.%" AND post_type = "post";
```

И второй где значение id должно браться из перового запроса

```
SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Какая будет ошибка?

```
SELECT id,post_title, 
(SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = wp.id) ss
FROM wp_posts wp WHERE post_title LIKE '%д.%' AND post_type = 'post';
```

Скорее всего так:

```
SELECT wp.id,wp.post_title, ss.guid
FROM wp_posts wp join
(SELECT guid, post_parent FROM wp_posts) ss on ss.post_parent = wp.id
WHERE wp.post_title LIKE '%д.%' AND wp.post_type = 'post';
```

Comment: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Я так и думал. :-)

Comment: А второй вариант?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'ss.post_parent' in 'on clause'

Comment: Копипаст. Поправил.

Comment: 48 Ул. 2-я Квессиская, д.11 http://apart5.com/wpcontent/uploads/2013/12/img1....
48 Ул. 2-я Квессиская, д. 11 http://apart5.com/?p=50

Сейчас выдает две строки на каждый id, мне нужна та где url картинки

Comment: Забавно...